# Getting error in server.j while login with jwt. TypeError: jws.sign is not a function at module.exports [as sign]

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt

This is my controller:

```
import getPrismaInstance from "../utils/PrismaClient.js";
import { config } from "dotenv";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { comparePassword, hashPassword } from "../utils/PasswordGenerator.js";

config();

export const AdminLogin = async (req, res, next) => {
 try {
   const { email, password } = req.body;
   if (!email || !password) {
   return res.json({ msg: "All fields are required.", status: false });
  }
 const prisma = getPrismaInstance();
 const admin = await prisma.admin.findUnique({ where: { email } });
  if (!admin) {
   return res.json({ msg: "Admin not found", status: false });
 } else {
  const adminPassword = password.toString();
  const match = await comparePassword(adminPassword, admin.password);
  if (!match) return res.status(400).send("Wrong password");

  const payload = {
    email: admin.email,
    id: admin.id,
  };
  const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "2h",
  });

  console.log(token);

  admin.password = undefined;
  res.cookie("token", token, {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2592000000),
    httpOnly: true,
    // secure: true, // only works on https
  });

   return res.json({ msg: "Admin found", status: true, data: admin });
 }
 } catch (err) {
  next(err);
 }
};
```

Getting error in server.js while  login with jwt:

> TypeError: jws.sign is not a function at module.exports [as sign].

How can I  complete my project? I install jsonwebtoken already. but still getting error all required package are install.

This is my index.js:

```
import { config } from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import express, { json } from "express";
import AdminRoutes from "./routes/AdminRoutes.js"
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

config();
const app = express();

 app.use(
 cors({
   origin: "*",
 })
);
app.use(json());
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use("/api/admin", AdminRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
 console.log(`Server started on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
 });
```